# Remove spacings in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: charts, spacing

I like tight layouts with no unnecessary spacing. How can I do that with `BoxWhiskerChart?`

The `BarSpacing` option controls spacings between boxes, but it does not change horizontal spacings between boxes and outer frames.

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[55, 10], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[65, 10], 1000];
BoxWhiskerChart[{{data1, data2}},BarSpacing -> Tiny]
```

[image]

Is there any easy option to achieve a tight layout in `BoxWhiskerChart` with less spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[55, 10], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[65, 10], 1000];
bw1 = BoxWhiskerChart[{{data1, data2}}, BarSpacing -> Large]
```

Check:

```
AbsoluteOptions[bw1, PlotRange]
```

> {PlotRange -> {{0.25, 2.75}, {15.6546, 100.943}}}

and try this:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{data1, data2}}
 , BarSpacing -> Tiny
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 2.5}, {15, 100}}
 , ImageSize -> Medium
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[55, 10], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[65, 10], 1000];

data = {{data1, data2}};
```

You can also use the option [`PlotRangePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) as follows:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
 BarSpacing -> .05, 
 PlotRangePadding -> -1/Length[First @ data]]
```

[image]